# make htaccess rules just for some folders

Tags: .htaccess

i want to access videos in my site example:

live.example.com/video1/1.mp4?token

so if i dont add **?token**  it will redirect to redirect.mp4

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=token
RewriteRule \.mp4$ http://live.example.com/redirect.mp4 [R=302,L]
```

i use this code  but how to make it just for those folders:

video1, video2, video3

so what i want is to make rule just for mp4 files that are on video1, video2, video3 folder so they will play just if i add ?token at end of .mp4

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=token
RewriteRule ^(?:video1|video2|video3)/[^/]+\.mp4$ http://example.com/redirect.mp4 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: What was the exact address you visited? Are you sure it wasn't a cached redirect in your browser?

Comment: i visit example.com/video/123.mp4?token  and it redirect me to example.com/redirect.mp4

Comment: It must be cached in your browser. Clear your cache for the site and try again.

Comment: i tried but same, also when i delete your code from htaccess  then it works normally (but it can be accessed without ?token too)

Comment: i use this on supdomain, is that problem? : live.example.com/video1/123.mp4?token

Comment: No that doesn't matter. What are you actually using as the token? I think there is something going wrong in the way that you're doing it, that is being missed when you change it to an example to ask the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134536/discussion-between-arpak-and-superduperapps).